# MySQL Migration Toolkit syntax error when creating schema

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

There is something wrong with the SQL after this error, and I'm not sure what.

Error: You have an error in your SQL Syntax. Please check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(0), PRIMARY KEY (`AddressID`), CONSTRAINT `FK_Address_Profile` FOREIGN KEY ' at line 15

and here is the create syntax:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MyDB_dbo`.`Address`;
CREATE TABLE `MyDB_dbo`.`Address` (
  `AddressID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProfileID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `Address1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `Address2` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `State` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `ZipCode` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `ZipPlus` VARCHAR(6) NULL,
  `Country` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `MailReturned` DATETIME NULL,
  `DPVStatus` VARCHAR(1) NULL,
  `DateCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `StaffID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `Active` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
  PRIMARY KEY (`AddressID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Address_Profile` FOREIGN KEY `FK_Address_Profile` (`ProfileID`)
    REFERENCES `MyDB_dbo`.`Profile` (`ProfileID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Is there something wrong with the CONSTRAINT keyword or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should there be () around the DEFAULT (0)?

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I have another syntax error I'm about to post related to a diagram in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
  `Active` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
```

change to

```
  `Active` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```